# Why does my print execute after the second loop even if I use print first?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I'm a beginner of python, and I wanted to try to make a timer.

```
import time

sets=int(input("How many sets?: "))
seconds=int(input("How many seconds per set?: "))

for i in range(sets):
    print("set {0} of {1} started".format(i + 1, sets))
    for j in range(seconds, 0, -1):
        print(j, end=" ")
print("Finished workout! Good Job!")
```

The problem is that the first print in the first loop is active after the j loop is ended, and I don't know why.
Also my version of py is 3.11, I'm sorry if I misinterpreted the python-3.x tag.

I expected the output to be:

```
How many sets?: 3
How many seconds per set?: 2
set 1 of 3 started
2 1
set 2 of 3 started
2 1
set 3 of 3 started
2 1
Finished workout! Good Job!
```

But it's

```
How many sets?: 3
How many seconds per set?: 2
2 1 
set 1 of 3 started
2 1 
set 2 of 3 started
2 1 
set 3 of 3 started
Finished workout! Good Job!
```

Please help and thank you! :)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I get almost the desired output, there are just no line breaks between the `2 1` and the "next" line (because you never print one). It's most definitely *not* inverting the inner/outer print as shown.

Comment: I can confirm MisterMiyagi's report, the behaviour I see (and expected) is that the "2 1" appears as a prefix of the next line, and at the same time rather than after each second. But that is a normal function of line-buffered IO (when the output doesn't have newlines),

Comment: Also, you probably want `flush=True` when printing `j`. Otherwise, buffering won't print anything until a newline.

Comment: I suspect you just need to add `print()` after the `for j` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `print` terminates with a newline character. When you define `end` in the print function, you modify this behavior. I have added a bare `print` which will simply output a newline character to stdout, correcting the format issues.

```
for i in range(sets):
    print("set {0} of {1} started".format(i + 1, sets))
    for j in range(seconds, 0, -1):
        print(j, end=" ")
    print()
print("Finished workout! Good Job!")
```

I would also like to add, that if you're on windows and using something like git-bash or powershell to test your code, you may need to flush stdout after a `print` to have your text displayed in the proper order.

`print("Hello World!", flush=True)`

If this applies to your situation, make sure you test, as over flushing the buffer can cause a lot of lag in your application.